# Delphi XE: Where is my TValue.Equals()?

Tags: delphi, equality, rtti, tvalue

It seems that one, in my opinion mandatory method is missing from TValue; TValue.Equals(TValue).

So whats a fast and decent way of comparing 2 TValues, preferably without the use of TValue.ToString(), which allows false matches between variants, records, etc.

Comment: I think DeHL (now discontinued) has some some stuff to do this. Don't know specifics. http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Delphi-Mocks](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/Delphi-Mocks/blob/master/Delphi.Mocks.Helpers.pas) presents two functions :

```
function CompareValue(const Left,Right : TValue): Integer;
function SameValue(const Left, Right: TValue): Boolean;
```

With the record helper for TValue you can also do `TValue.Equals(TValue);`

Licensed under Apache terms and under permission by Stefan Glienke.

Here is the original source by Stefan : [delphisorcery](http://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/source/browse/trunk/Source/Core/DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas).

If you need to extend the functionality for variants, add:

```
function TValueHelper.IsVariant: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TypeInfo = System.TypeInfo(Variant);
end;
```

and insert

```
if Left.IsVariant and Right.IsVariant then
begin
  Result := Left.AsVariant = Right.AsVariant;
end else
```

after the isString comparison in the `SameValue` function.

Comment: Upvote for the link, but it seems its still incomplete (for instance, determining the equality of variants is missing). I am looking for a smaller version, comparing e.g. memory adresses.

Comment: @Marius You can simply add the missing functionality yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True, though that would render my initial question obsolete :p

Comment: @Marius Not at all. You can build on top of Stefan's code. That's what I mean. Start from Stefan's code and what the little extra that you need.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Just joking with you, i'll have a look at reusing his code and amending any missing functionalities.

Comment: @Marius Feel free to contribute to the [original source]( http://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/source/browse/trunk/Source/Core/DSharp.Core.Reflection.pas).